# SQL Plus - SET command not affecting the script being ran

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to run the following SQLPlus* set of commands:

```
/usr/tmp/> sqlplus -s / @my_test_script param1 param2 <<-EOF
SET ECHO OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGES 0
SET LINESIZE 400
EXIT
EOF
```

The SET commands are supposed to suppress the output from the script I'm running - but they have no effect, since the script itself probably has a different "scope" for ECHO, HEADING, etc.
The output is suppressed only once I move all those SET commands into the script-file itself.

Since this piece of code should eventually turn into a generic script for running other SQL scripts, putting those SET command inside every script is not a good solution.

Does anyone know of a way to force the SET command values over scripts ran within the same SQLPlus* "session"?

Comment: I think the `set` commands you are redirecting to sqlplus are running _after_ the script.

Comment: Your here-document string as defined on the first line is "-EOF" but you close it with only "EOF" (no dash in front).  Remove the dash before the 'E' on the first line. NEVER MIND I just read that the dash ignores leading TABs in the here-doc lines. Thanks for letting me learn something today!  lol

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Shannon. You could try the following code (which changes the ordering a little bit):

```
/usr/tmp/> sqlplus -s / <<-EOF
SET ECHO OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGES 0
SET LINESIZE 400
@my_test_script param1 param2
EXIT
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

if I remember well, you could call from every script this initializing script using @@ command. for example:

```
@@init.sql
```

[source](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus.html)

**EDIT**

also, from the oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a90842/ch3.htm) :

> SQL*Plus also supports a User Profile, executed after the Site Profile. This file is generally named login.sql. SQL*Plus searches for the user profile in your current directory, and then the directories you specify with the SQLPATH environment variable. SQL*Plus searches this colon-separated list of directories in the order they are listed.
>
> You can add any SQL commands, PL/SQL blocks, or SQL*Plus commands to your user profile. When you start SQL*Plus, it automatically searches for your user profile and runs the commands it contains.